# Share multiple y_axis in Plotly Subplots

Tags: python, plotly

I need some help to understand how I can share multiple y_axis for all of the columns in the same row in Plotly Subplots. I know that I can share the y_axis by adding ‘shared_yaxes =True’, however, how can I share multiple y_axis. There are 3 y_axis (time1, time2, and depth) that are shared among many columns, and  I would like to position time1 and time2 next to each other at the very beginning of the columns and depth y_axis at the end.
Please see the picture below, this is how I want my plot to look.
I couldn't find any similar questions on StackOverflow or Plotly community, and I couldn't find anything in plotly documentation.
Thanks, appreciate any help on this.

[image]

Comment: Please refer to the [official reference](https://plotly.com/python/multiple-axes/#multiple-axes) for an example of adding multiple axes to a single graph. This can be represented by a single graph instead of subplots.

Comment: Thanks, to my best understanding the official reference shows how to assign the multiple y axis for different plots. There is a y_axis for each plot. How can I share multiple y_axis for all the plots, as all of the plots in my case use the same 3 y_axis?

Comment: Looking at the attached images, I can determine that they are different graphs, are they not?

Comment: Yes they are different plots, but they all share the same three y_axis, namely time1, time2 and depth (as you can see the time axises at the beginning and depth is last one)

Comment: These plots are built using special software, I am wondering if the same can be done using Plotly.

Comment: Did you get the correct answer? I have the same question...

Comment: @VickyDing no I ended up using matplotlib.

Answer (score 0):

From looking at your image

- there are multiple traces.  Each trace appears to use it's own **xaxis** as it is a stream down the figure
- each of the traces can use one of three **yaxis**.  Hence have simulated a dataframe for data.  Then created a figure, randomly assigning one of the **yaxis** to each trace
- then case of formating layout of axis when complete.  Question is focused on **yaxis**.  Hence these have been placed according to statements

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        **{
            "y1": pd.date_range("11-apr-2021", freq="2H", periods=100),
            "y2": np.linspace(36, 95, 100),
            "y3": np.linspace(17000, 19000, 100),
        },
        **{f"x{x}": np.random.uniform(0, 5, 100) for x in range(1, 8)},
    }
)

go.Figure(
    [
        go.Scatter(x=df[x], y=df[y], yaxis=y, xaxis=x, name=x + y)
        for x in df.columns
        if x[0] == "x"
        for y in np.random.choice([c for c in df.columns if c[0] == "y"], 1)
    ]
).update_layout(
    **{
        c.replace("x", "xaxis"): {
            "domain": [max((int(c[1]) / 7) - 1 / 7, 0.05), int(c[1]) / 7]
        }
        for c in df.columns
        if c[0] == "x"
    }
).update_layout(
    yaxis={"position": 0},
    yaxis2={"position": 0.05, "overlaying": "y"},
    yaxis3={"side": "right", "overlaying": "y", "position": 1},
)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank Rob, I will give it a go, and I will let you know how it goes! Cheers

Comment: Hi Rob, does each trace have to use only one of the y axis? Is it possible to get all of the x_axis use all three y axis. For instance if I zoom on any one of the plots, every other plot gets zoomed with all 3 y axis zoomed as well.

Comment: a scatter/line has an xaxis and yaxis.  an individual trace to have multiple yaxis is really a departure from this core concept.  if what you are saying - each point has 3 candidate y-values you could simulate this by creating additional traces

Comment: Thanks Rob, assuming I have only primary and secondary y_axis for each x_axis, is there any way to share the secondary y_axis in the same way I share primary y_axis (shared_yaxes=True)

Comment: I really think about it differently.  A figure can have many x and y axis.  A trace has one xaxis and one yaxis.  Primary / secondary yaxis are really different traces using different yaxis.  Think about your core object model, being a figure that contains traces.  each trace is a list of x-values and a list of y-values.

Comment: OK, Yes I see your point. How would you approach to create a number of plots let's say, weather conditions, humidity, temperature, wind speed ... etc, and they all are on xaxis, while on my yaxis I have DateTime (month day hour min sec) and elapsed time (in seconds). So all of these xaxis (weather conditions) have to be plotted against two common yaxis, and I should be able to zoom at any point in the subplot so that every plot gets zoomed. Is it possible to accomplish using Plotly? I know there are ways to do it using matplotlib which I am also exploring.